# Customize windows at opening of Emacs

Tags: windows, linux, bash, emacs, split

I want to start three files in emacs from a terminal, and split the window in emacs into three, so that the three windows contains one file each. It is also important to me that the windows is divided in a certain way. I can get the right split manually by opening emacs, and pressing C-x 3, C-x o, C-x 2. Anyone knows how to do this either by configurating .emacs or by bash-scripting? I am to open about 300 files this way, so doing it automatically would help me out a lot.

EDIT:
I am to open 3 different files each time. I would love if I could open from terminal like this:
emacs file1 file2 file3

then for the next three files
emacs file4 file 5 file6

Just in case:
- Running Linux
- Using emacs-newest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
(defun open-files (first second third)
  (interactive "fFirst: \nfSecond: \nfThird: ")
  (find-file first)
  (split-window-horizontally)
  (other-window 1)
  (find-file second)
  (split-window-vertically)
  (other-window 1)
  (find-file third))
```

**Edit**: I've made the function interactive, it is also possible to call it from the command line like so:

```
emacs --eval='(open-files "/tmp/first" "/tmp/second" "/tmp/third")'
```

You could probably wrap this in a bash script to make it easier to call.

Comment: Sorry if I was vague. I am to open 3 different files each time. Is that possible with your code? If it is, how? =)

Comment: But the splitting of the windows was spot on!

Comment: Do you mean you want Emacs to prompt you for the filenames?

Comment: That would work, but I would love if I could open from terminal like this: emacs file1 file2 file3

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted!